# Vue loader after updating breaks slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, slot, vue-loader

I'm not sure what's going on here, I updated webpack-encore and vue loader to the most recent versions, and suddenly the HTML for slots compiles into something really weird.

It's just a simple

```
<template>
    <div class="form-inline pull-left filter-panel">
        <slot name="left-actions"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

in one component, and in another component:

```
<template slot="left-actions">
    <h2 class="channelTitle">{{ $t('channelTitle') }}</h2>
</template>
```

Before the update this compiles to

```
<div data-v-57aa5baa="" class="form-inline pull-left filter-panel">
    <h2 data-v-224716e3="" data-v-57aa5baa="" class="channelTitle">Channels</h2> <!---->
</div>
```

And it shows up fine, but after the update I get this weird #document-fragment thing, in a template? And it's not even visible.

```
<div data-v-57aa5baa="" class="form-inline pull-left filter-panel">
    <template data-v-391862db="" data-v-57aa5baa="" style="">

        #document-fragment
        <h2 data-v-224716e3="" data-v-57aa5baa="" class="channelTitle">Master feeds</h2>

    </template> <!---->
</div>
```

What causes this? I had to update css selectors in vue from `/deep/` to `::v-deep`, could that have something to do with it? The updating didn't go well?

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@cospired/i18n-iso-languages": "^2.1.2",
    "@handsontable/vue": "^2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "gsap": "^3.7.1",
    "handsontable": "^4.0.0",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^6.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.isempty": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.keys": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash.map": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
    "lodash.orderby": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.snakecase": "^4.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.15.2",
    "v-calendar": "^2.0.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.1.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-async-computed": "^3.8.2",
    "vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.1.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-drag-drop": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.11.2",
    "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.26",
    "vue-modal-dialogs": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.13",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-select": "git+https://github.com/eriknygren/vue-select.git#3aec695",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.0",
    "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.6.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.25",
    "ajv": "^6.5.4",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.7.0",
    "babel-preset-modern-browsers": "^12.0.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.0.0-rc.11",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cypress": "^6.9.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "is-docker": "^1.1.0",
    "karma": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-webpack": "^5.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.4",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "postcss-import": "^11.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "postcss-url": "^7.3.2",
    "sass": "^1.43.4",
    "sass-loader": "^12.3.0",
    "speed-measure-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.7.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had normalize.css included which does

`display:none` on `template` tags, which broke visibility. Kind of annoying but I see the cause now.